# CpiContext::new_with_signer privilege escalation

Tags: anchor, pda, cpi, signer

I've been having this problem for a few weeks now.
First, I'm creating a PDA for managing campaigns:

```
pub struct CreateCampaign<'info> {
        #[account(
            init,
            payer = seller,
            space = 200,
            seeds = [
                seller.key().as_ref(),
                b"_mff_",
                timestamp.to_le_bytes().as_ref(),
            ],
            bump
        )]
        pub campaign: Account<'info, Campaign>,
        #[account(mut)]
        pub seller: Signer<'info>,
...
```

Then I proceed to create a mint, initialize it and set the mint authority for the PDA address:

```
let create_account_accounts = CreateAccount {
            from: ctx.accounts.seller.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
        };

        let create_account_cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            create_account_accounts,
        );

        let rent_balance = Rent::get()?.minimum_balance(82);

        system_program::create_account(
            create_account_cpi_ctx,
            rent_balance,
            82,
            &ctx.accounts.token_program.key(),
        )?;


        let initialize_mint_accounts = token::InitializeMint {
            mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
        };

        let initialize_mint_cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            initialize_mint_accounts,
        );

        token::initialize_mint(
            initialize_mint_cpi_ctx,
            0,
            &ctx.accounts.campaign.key(), // transfer the mint authority to PDA
            Some(&ctx.accounts.campaign.key()),
        )?;
```

Until this point, everything works as expected. Checking the token mint account in solana explorer confirms that the mint authority is set to the PDA.
The problem starts when I try to mint any token using the PDA as signer. This is my context.

```
 #[derive(Accounts)]
    pub struct BuyerEditBid<'info> {
        #[account(mut, has_one = buyer)]
        pub bid: Account<'info, Bid>,
        #[account(mut)]
        pub campaign: Account<'info, Campaign>,

        #[account(mut)]
        pub buyer: Signer<'info>,

        #[account(mut)]
        pub mint: Account<'info, token::Mint>,

        /// CHECK: We'll create this with Metaplex if bid is closed
        // #[account(mut)]
        // pub metadata: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
        /// CHECK: We'll create this with Anchor if bid is closed
        #[account(mut)]
        pub token_account: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
...
```

Then I run this function:

```
fn mint_closed_bid_token(accounts: &mut BuyerEditBid) -> Result<()> {
        
        associated_token::create(CpiContext::new(
            accounts.associated_token_program.to_account_info(),
            associated_token::Create {
                payer: accounts.buyer.to_account_info(),
                associated_token: accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
                authority: accounts.buyer.to_account_info(),
                mint: accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                system_program: accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                token_program: accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                rent: accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
            },
        ))?;

        let seller = accounts.campaign.seller.key();
        let timestamp = accounts.campaign.timestamp.to_le_bytes();
        let seeds = [seller.as_ref(), "_mff_".as_bytes(), timestamp.as_ref()];
        let signer_seeds = &[&seeds[..]][..];


        msg!("seeds signer {:?}", signer_seeds);

        let result = token::mint_to(
            CpiContext::new_with_signer(
                accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
                token::MintTo {
                    mint: accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
                    to: accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
                    authority: accounts.campaign.to_account_info(),
                },
                signer_seeds,
            ),
            u64::from(accounts.bid.amount),
        );
```

To my surprise, I get the not so unusual error:
`Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account`
Any ideas why? I've checked the seeds, even used `PublicKey::find_program_address`to confirm that the seeds are correct. In fact, they are.
Why do I get this (not so descriptive) error? I can't mark my campaign account as signer. Should this error run in PDA owned accounts, when their seeds are correct?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're deriving the signer_seeds wrongly. Here's how to do it:

```
let seeds = &[
     seller.as_ref(),
     "_mff_".as_bytes(),
     &[campaign_bump]
];

let signer_seeds = &[&seeds[..]];
```

The `campaign_bump`, exactly as its name implies, is the bump of the campaign account.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I wasn't storing the bump in the PDA as after anchor 0.21.0, we can't use the bump in the initializer (I mean, bump = bump), I thought it wasn't necessary. It is though, in order to sign.

I appreciate your help, thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to be of help